# Converting mesh shell into solid body

Tags: meshlab, solidworks, ansys

I have a `.obj` file of an geometry and when I open it on MeshLab it opens as a shell i.e. hollow object. Is there a way to fill (and mesh) the shell?
Note: Need not be necessary that I use MeshLab

[image: The geometry I want to perform a simulation on]

[image: How the geometry opens in ANSYS thermal]

I need to remesh the object to perform the simulation so every face of the mesh is treated as a face and not a mesh. I remesh has to be done on a 3D body so can I fill the body to make is a solid 3D object instead of a surface 3D object?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you provide a picture? Meshes are generally represented by their hull -- what dou you want to fill it with? What is your application for this?

Comment: I've added images for reference.
As you mention, the geometry is a hull and I need it to be a solid object.

Comment: I am not sure how to do it in MeshLab but several CAD packages have this capability. For example, in SpaceClaim (part of ANSYS) you right-click on the mesh object and select "convert into solid".

Comment: I've tried using SpaceClaim's "Convert to solid" option but during meshing it breaks each triangular face on the surface into an individual surface (which is to be expected) but then gives an error with the geometry.

Comment: I figured out how to do it using SpaceClaim. When you use the "convert to solid" option don't merge the faces. If you merge the faces then the problem I mentioned before occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Meshlab does not have the concept of a "solid" or "hollow" mesh. As long as your mesh is closed and manifold (it looks like yours is - if it isn't, you can probably fix it using a combination of filters like `Cleaning and Repairing -> Repair non Manifold edges by removing faces` and `Remeshing, Simplification and Reconstruction -> Close Holes`), this is something you will need to configure in your simulation software.

Answer (score 0):

Solidworks 2021 can open obj files
[image: Open file extensions]

If those triangles are imported as separate surfaces, you can use "Knit Surface" from the surfaces toolbar to make them as one and even better make a solid out of it (there may be not gaps between the triangles in this case)
[image: Knit Surface options to use]

Comment: I've imported the .obj file directly to Solidworks as a potential solution before. The body opens as a single entity. No gaps/openings. But when I try to save it as a .step file it instead makes an error file.

Comment: is it possible for you to upload the file?

Comment: I "figured" out the problem and by that I mean - I know what to do but not why I should be doing this...
When I open the file on SolidWorks it opens as a surface geometry (even though I've selected the Solid Geometry option while loading the object). But when I open the STL file in SpaceClaim it opens as a solid object. Since my aim is to use ANSYS this works out for me.